# Why does Console.ReadKey() concatenate 'a' symbol to the next output?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I'm doing a simple example where depending the input key I write a different message on the console. The problem is that every time I read a key, the next `Console.WriteLine()` result has an 'a' symbol concatenated at the start? Here's an example:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfor = Console.ReadKey();
if (keyInfor.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Up arrow");
}
```

Expected Result when I click Up Arrow: "Up arrow"

Actual Result: "aUp arrow"

Comment: when you press the `a` Button?

Comment: It just writes `Up arrow` on me. Are you sure your up arrow _might_ seen as a `a` because of some unicode differences or something?

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: It is possible and no, I'm not executing `Console.WriteLine("a")` before. @Wojtek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me it shows a space. Note that the description of `Console.ReadKey()` says:

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. **The pressed key is optionally displayed in the console window.**

if you want to disable it, do

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfor = Console.ReadKey(true);
```

In this way there won't be any output for the key.

Note that if you redirect the output of your program, you'll see that the space isn't a space, it is a `NUL` character (`\0`)